# Formatting numpy savetext values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working in a project where a mobile robot roams in a 4 wall configured ground. Each wall has a unique shape (square, triangle) in it. The robot detects the shape and calculates the distance between robot to wall and export it.

the desired results like

```
Timestamp    A     B      C    D

xxxxx        0     12     0    0

yyyyy        21    0      0    0
```

The current code exports the distance whether its A or B or C or D next column to timestamp. But i want 0 as value of A and B and D, if it detected C.

```
Timestamp    A     B      C    D

xxxxx        41    0      0    0

yyyyy        21    0      0    0
```

Can anyone help me on it?

```
if area > 200:
            cv2.drawContours(frame, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)

        if len(approx) == 3:


            timestamped_camera_readings = np.append(timestamped_camera_readings, (((154*58)/(perimeter/4))*0.2645 ))
        elif len(approx) == 4:


            timestamped_camera_readings = np.append(timestamped_camera_readings, (((154*58)/(perimeter/4))*0.2645 ))

        elif len(approx) == 5:


            timestamped_camera_readings = np.append(timestamped_camera_readings, (((154*58)/(g/5))*0.2645 ))



write_fmt = " ".join("%4.2f" for _ in timestamped_camera_readings)
# append time

timestamped_camera_readings = np.append(float(timestamp),timestamped_camera_readings)
write_fmt += " %.0f"

with open("camera_diatanceee.txt", "ab") as ff:
    np.savetxt(ff, np.expand_dims(timestamped_camera_readings, axis=0),fmt='%f')
```

Comment: so what is your exact problem? What does it output now?

Comment: Is your problem that it does not output `xxxx 0 0 1 0` if it detects C at 1 m? But outputs `xxxx 1 0 0 0` instead?

Comment: yep , absolutely thats the problem.

Comment: You put too much code in your question. Do you know where it goes wrong exactly? Please debug it as far as you can.

Comment: For example can you pinpoint which line does not give the result you expect?

Comment: is cv2 what you expect in the `cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
` line? Please format some example and post that result instead of your code before that.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is `timestamped_camera_readings`? I only see you adding values to it once. Assuming it's a list of values, none of your code changes order of it (except the part where you append timestamp to the beginning) so that means you add values to `timestamped...` in the wrong order. I suggest you make it a dictionary instead and then unpack values properly. Or pre-initialize (arr=np.zeros((4)) and write values to correct places (according to `len(approx)`) in the array instead of appending.

Comment: yes , ill go with the second option. 
gracious.